# TPL email template in Symfony2

Tags: php, email, templates, symfony, view

I used a very simple template (.tpl) for receive emails in my php application. Some similar this:

```
Date    : {date}
Name    : {name}
Mail    : {email}
Subject : {subject}

{message}
```

Now, I have migrated this app to Symfony, ¿how can I used this template?

If I do:

```
$this->renderView('MyBundle:Template:support.tpl', $params), 'text/html');
```

This not work in Symfony2.

Any Idea??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony doesn't know .tpl files and your syntax. Simply use twig!

```
Date    : {{ date }}
Name    : {{ name }}
Mail    : {{ email }}
Subject : {{ subject }}

{{ message }}
```

Of course your file have to end to `.twig`

```
$this->renderView('MyBundle:Template:support.txt.twig', $params);
```